# Job status progress bar with Spring framework

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, statusbar

In a web application I want to show a progress bar for a long server-side job.
I think the process is almost standard:

1. Client requests a job via Ajax
2. Server starts this job in a separate thread and replies to the client that the job has started.
3. Client starts a status request with a fixed time interval
4. Server reply to status request querying the job thread, getting the status (job running/finished/error). In case of running, state a percentage of completion.

Is there something for this purpose in the Spring framework?

Comment: Two close vote without a comment...

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - this question is either too broad (to answer involves application specific client and server code which is likely be opinion based rather than definitive) or seems to fall into 'recommend a library' with the suggestion that Spring may solve your problem (I don't believe it will).  Given you have the basics how this would work (although you should use an application server rather than spawning threads in you web-server and web-sockets rather than polling with AJAX) you should try to implement something and come back with specific problems.

Comment: I do not agree with you. I'm asking if a specific well-known framework (Spring) has something for a specific purpose, this can't be confused with  'recommend a library' because I'm declaring the library. I'm not asking code but just if this framework is considering this pattern.
Moreover I cannot understand how this scenario could work without threading and status polling from the client, but this can be my lack. I think that a web-server with a mvc framework could be an application server. Am I wrong?

Comment: This scenario needs threading, just you shouldn't be creating the threads (and certainly not in the web-server - doing additional work in the web-server will limit its ability to do its job - responding to http requests).  I'd look to use a Message-Driven-Bean; you post a message in response to a HTTP request, which is processed by the MDB when their are sufficient resources and posts status messages as it runs.  The status messages should be pushed to the client browser over a web-socket to avoid polling.

Comment: For 'thread' I did not mean a web-server thread to receive http messages, I mean a service java thread to run the job asynchronously made by `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();` and called from a spring controller in a Apache Tomcat  container. I will study web-sockets because http requests are the only communication I know from client to server. Thank you sincerely.

Comment: Using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor` is the problem - what do you think will happen if you got 10k requests?  Your code will try to create 10k threads - this might work depending on your hardware but you should avoid the problem by using a queue based mechanism, which JMS/MDB is an ideal candidate.  The whole point of the J2EE containers are that they manage the resources (a thread being a resource) to control the load on the server; by creating adhoc threads you would be circumventing these controls

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar about which you're asking are mostly used for uploading and downloading the large files where you can easily calculate the file size that has been downloaded or uploaded as oppose to original file size, and usually done using scripts, Spring doesn't supports such progress bar functionality.

Comment: Thank you, my problem is a bit different from data transfer because the progression of this remote job cannot be calculate from the client (like an upload/download).

Comment: I have worked on Spring and never found such thing, when I was required the progression, I have used the JavaScript.

Comment: Of course I will use Javascript to show and manage the progress bar, but progression data (status and percentage of completition) is given by the server.